# search.ismatch only matching with first letter in the search

Tags: odata, azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I have an azure cognitive search index and I am using search.ismatch ODATA full text search function to return records that match a particular key work.

Data

- Apple
- Pineapple

  search.ismatch('apple', 'Text')

I am expecting the query to return both values but I am only getting 1. i.e. It only matches first letters in the word.

How to return the data regardless where the search text within the data?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to search based on substring of text is by using `ngarm tokenizer` in your index `schema`.

```py
index_definition = {
    "name": index_name,
    "fields": [
        {"name": "id", "type": "Edm.String", "key": True, "searchable": False},
        {
            "name": "Text",
            "type": "Edm.String",
            "searchable": True,
            "analyzer": "custom_analyzer",
        },
    ],
    "analyzers": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
            "name": "custom_analyzer",
            "tokenizer": "custom_tokenizer",
            "tokenFilters": ["lowercase"],
        }
    ],
    "tokenizers": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.NGramTokenizer",
            "name": "custom_tokenizer",
            "minGram": 5,
            "maxGram": 5,
        }
    ],
}
```

With above schema I have uploaded the given sample data:

```py
documents = [
    {"@search.action": "upload", "id": "1", "Text": "apple"},
    {"@search.action": "upload", "id": "2", "Text": "pineapple"},
]
```

With the above index definition and data, I was able to get the required results.
[image]

**Note:** This is sample code for demonstration, you might to have to modify and reconfigure based on your requirement.

For more details related to partial search, you can check this [documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-partial-matching)